# Using cookies for authentication is working on postman but chrome doesn't save them

Tags: vue.js, express, authentication, cookies, cors

I'm making this post as detailed as possible, because I've been stuck with my authentication with cookies for almost a week now, and despite my numerous searches, I can't find any solutions.

I've created a TypeScript API with express for a Vue3 application using the Quasar framework.
For user management, I chose to save a token in my cookies at login, then to check for the presence of this token in the request cookies of each API call made from my application. This verification is carried out in my API middleware.

When I test authentication with cookies in postman, everything works perfectly.

When I make another request (which goes through my middleware, which checks that the session token exists in a cookie), there's no problem, the cookie is in my header and the request works.

When I go into my Vue application and make my login API call, it seems to work fine :

- I have a cookie in my response
- In my header, the set-cookie value is defined

But when I go to application --> Storage --> Cookies, the cookie hasn't been saved.

**Response headers :**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: sessionToken=8e4c50dd42f0087f7dd5946257624fbeb81721e0bc049f5160f207adf502c0c3; Domain=localhost; Path=/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 233
ETag: W/"e9-5Roa5NwLavDOf+4KqSdRTxdmTQk"
Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2023 19:38:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

**Request headers :**

```
2/95 requests
902 B/7.6 MB transferred
115 kB/9.9 MB resources
Finish: 14.70 s
DOMContentLoaded: 794 ms
Load: 1.13 s
Request URL:
http://localhost:8000/auth/login
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
[::1]:8000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: sessionToken=8e4c50dd42f0087f7dd5946257624fbeb81721e0bc049f5160f207adf502c0c3; Domain=localhost; Path=/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 233
ETag: W/"e9-5Roa5NwLavDOf+4KqSdRTxdmTQk"
Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2023 19:38:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:8001
Referer: http://localhost:8001/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

I haven't found any way to store or retrieve the cookie that is returned in my API login response.

Then, when I try to make a new API call that requires user authentication via the cookie (here I've taken the logout example). I get the error message that my request doesn't contain a session Token in the response cookie.

**Response headers :**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 47
ETag: W/"2f-b09VFP4C6zLoQv74QS1t/iBcRTM"
Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2023 19:27:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

**Request headers :**

```
POST /auth/logout HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:8000
Origin: http://localhost:8001
Referer: http://localhost:8001/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

### API configuration and code

**idex.ts :**

```js
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
  })
);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`Server listening on port http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`, {
    callingFile: getFileName(__filename),
  });
});
```

**authenticationController.ts** (with login and logout functions) **:**

```js
export async function login(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
  try {
    .
    .
    .

    const salt = random();
    user.authentication.sessionToken = authentication(salt, user._id.toString());

    .
    .
    .

    res.cookie("sessionToken", user.authentication.sessionToken, {
      domain: "localhost",
      path: "/",
    });

    return res.status(200).json(safeOutput(user)).end();
  } catch (error) {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

I won't go into detail about the logout function, as the middleware blocks us before we can execute it.

**src\middlewares\index.ts :**

```js
export async function isAuthenticated(
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) {
  try {
    const sessionToken = req.cookies["sessionToken"];

    //I'm stuck at this point in the code
    if (!sessionToken) {
      logger.warn(ERROR_MESSAGES.UNAUTHORIZED_USER_NOT_CONNECTED.en, {
        callingFile: getFileName(__filename),
        callingFunction: "isAuthenticated",
      });
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ message: ERROR_MESSAGES.UNAUTHORIZED_USER_NOT_CONNECTED.fr })
        .end();
    }

    const existingUser = await getUserBySessionToken(sessionToken);

    if (!existingUser) {
      logger.warn(ERROR_MESSAGES.UNAUTHORIZED_USER_NOT_EXIST.fr, {
        callingFile: getFileName(__filename),
        callingFunction: "isAuthenticated",
      });
      return res.status(401).json({ message: ERROR_MESSAGES.UNAUTHORIZED_USER_NOT_EXIST.fr }).end();
    }

    merge(req, { identity: existingUser });

    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`${error}`, {
      callingFile: getFileName(__filename),
      callingFunction: "isAuthenticated",
    });
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }
}
```

**src\router\authentication.ts :**

```js
export default function (router: express.Router) {
  router.post("/auth/register", register);
  ...
  router.post("/auth/logout", isAuthenticated, logout);
}
```

### Vue app configuration and code

As I said earlier in my post, I used the quasar framework to create my app. But I don't think it has much impact on my problem.
Furthermore, I use axios to make my requests from my application.

**Axios configuration :**

```js
declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
  }
}

const api = axios.create({ withCredentials: true });

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  // for use inside Vue files (Options API) through this.$axios and this.$api

  app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;
  // ^ ^ ^ this will allow you to use this.$axios (for Vue Options API form)
  //       so you won't necessarily have to import axios in each vue file

  app.config.globalProperties.$api = api;
  // ^ ^ ^ this will allow you to use this.$api (for Vue Options API form)
  //       so you can easily perform requests against your app's API
});

export { api };
```

**API call** (for login and logout) **:**

```js
export async function loginApi(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
  return axios.post(BASE_INTERNAL_API_URL + AUTH_URL + LOGIN_URL, {
    email,
    password,
  });
}

export async function logoutApi(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  return axios.post(BASE_INTERNAL_API_URL + AUTH_URL + LOGOUT_URL);
}
```

As you can see from the details of my headers, I use localhost domains for dev.

*localhost:8000/* for API and *localhost:8001/* for Vue app

For now, the solution I'm using is to create a new shortcut for Google Chrome with an executable path as follows :
`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\tmpChromeSession"`

I don't have any cookie problems with this solution, but I wanted to know if there was any other option than modifying the chrome flags to disable its security.

I can't remember all the solutions I've tried, but I'll try to list a few.

Add { withCredentials: true } directly to my axios requests. As a result, my request doesn't even send anymore and I get a CORS error.

Change cookie parameters by specifying *path* and setting attributes such as *HttpOnly*, *Secure*, or *SameSite*.

Change corsOptions parameters by adding some attributes like *origin: '*'* or *exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"]*.

My authentication with cookies only worked once when I launched chrome with a special configuration so that it didn't take its security settings into account.

If you have an idea of how to solve my problem or if you want more details, don't hesitate, I really don't know what to do any more...

*Note :* I had to delete all my screenshots because stack-overflow considered my message as a spam :/